# ArrayBuffer converts to zero'd out Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraybuffer

I'm trying to convert an array buffer to a Uint8Array and it alwasy comes out as zeros.

```
buff = new ArrayBuffer(4)
buff[0] = 10
buff[1] = 10
buff[2] = 10
buff[3] = 10
console.log(new Uint8Array(buff))
 -> Uint8Array(4) [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the docs at [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)

> **You cannot directly manipulate the contents of an `ArrayBuffer`;** instead, you create one of the typed array objects or a DataView object which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer.

Comment: So let's say the array buffer is provided to me via `xmlhttp.response`, how would I convert it to a uint8array?

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar The conversion you do is valid, but you cannot alter the values of the buffer directly.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar although keep in mind that it is not really a conversion, it is merely a view-as